# POST returns 404 while GET works fine on Ajax call to SpringMVC controller

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc, post

I have to pass a long Base64 string from my JSP to my controller.
I have all my @requestmapping methods on my controller as GET methods.
when I tried to send my base64 string as a son value it threw an error stating issues with the header size.Some research lead me to understand that this is not an issue if my method accepts POST requests.

I have been using the same code for my get methods and they have been working fine...but when I changed it to post, it started to throw a 404.

Here is what I am doing :

JS  :

var search = {
                    "KEY" : "VALUE"
            }

```
        $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType : 'json',
                url : "/AjaxTest",
                data : JSON.stringify(search),
                success : function(result) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                    alert(e);
                },
                done : function(e) {
                    console.log("DONE");
                }
        });
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AjaxTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String AjaxTest(@RequestBody String MyData) {
        return MyData;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you check what do you get as posted url from your browser-> network and then clicking on the this request will give you the url, from there? As you are getting 404..

Comment: I see two problems here, first things your request mapping don’t specify consume and produce details. So I will first put those values as MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8. Secondly, I see that key value pair is coming as the part of request, but your method argument @requestBody is mapped to a string. Either change it to a pojo to match the key name or change your request structure. Let me know if those two things work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are specifying `type: "POST"`, but the actual jQuery.ajax function uses the `method` attribute to specify the http method. The reason `GET` works is because the method attribute defaults to `GET`.  Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType : 'application/json',
    url : "/AjaxTest",
    data : JSON.stringify(search),
    success : function(result) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        alert(e);
    },
    done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
});
```

Comment: now it gives me this error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Did you try specifying the dataType as 'application/json' instead of just application?